# Image collection filtering doesn't work in JavaScript client library Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, typeerror

I am trying to create a beautiful and intuitive interface for working with Google Earth Engine. In the process, I needed to filter the collection of satellite images. I get an error when calling any filter function.

What could be the mistake?

```js
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'Object' in undefined
at Function.ee.promote_ [as promoter_] (browser.js?9dfd:23586)
at ee.ApiFunction.ee.Function.promoteArgs (browser.js?9dfd:21333)
at ee.ApiFunction.ee.Function.apply (browser.js?9dfd:21310)
at ee.ApiFunction.ee.Function.call (browser.js?9dfd:21307)
at Function.ee.ApiFunction._call (browser.js?9dfd:21405)
at Function.ee.Filter.lt (browser.js?9dfd:21979)
```

Code example:

```js
const defaultShot = new ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
const filterShots = defaultShot.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
```

I am writing a SPA application in Vue CLI 3.

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace for the error?

Comment: @KevinReid, did you mean that? 
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'Object' in undefined
    at Function.ee.promote_ [as promoter_] (browser.js?9dfd:23586)
    at ee.ApiFunction.ee.Function.promoteArgs (browser.js?9dfd:21333)
    at ee.ApiFunction.ee.Function.apply (browser.js?9dfd:21310)
    at ee.ApiFunction.ee.Function.call (browser.js?9dfd:21307)
    at Function.ee.ApiFunction._call (browser.js?9dfd:21405)
    at Function.ee.Filter.lt (browser.js?9dfd:21979)

Comment: Yes, exactly. That helps clarify that the problem is definitely in the filter call. I don't have an answer for you about it, sorry. (By the way, in the future when someone asks for additional information, please make sure to [edit] it into your question — don't leave information only in comments.)